# fail to call axios in AWS Lambda located in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, axios, vpc

In my aws Lambda(nods.js) which located in VPC(public subnet), I call axios request but it did not work. When I run the lambda out side of the VPC, it work well. So, I think that is problem from VPC.
Since, I locate my RDS in that VPC I want to run lambda inside of vpc.

What is the problem of this situation? how can I solve it?

When I run lambda which contain axios request the lambda is give me time out error